# Changing border outline color in IE edge, and removing border default in Safari

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, safari, focus

I am using HTML CSS. In fire fox and chrome the border outline is white, the border looks like it is inside the box. However, the border outline in IE Edge is outside the box, not being able to see the white outline since it matches the white background. How can I target IE edge to give the border outline a black color, only for IE edge. Below is my code. How can I target safari to remove the default outlines when I hover? Thank you

```
button:focus {
    outline: 3px dotted rgba(231,231,231,1.00);
    outline-offset: -3px;
    color:red;
```

}

Comment: Could you please share the css code you are talking about?

Comment: Its really hard to offer any real suggestions without seeing an example, but have you looked into the `box-sizing` property?

Comment: its fine. I dont think there is code to target ie specifically, so that is ie end. Thanks for your time!